# How to make a runnable python app for MacOS

Tags: python, pyyaml

I have a project in PyCharm and python 3.7. I have big trouble to make a dist so I can run the project outside PyCharm, from the terminal in MacOS. When I run the project inside PyCharm everything works fine, but it seems that I cant figure it out how to make a build / dist. I have tried pyinstaller and py2app. When I build a smaller testproject I success to do a dist but not with my larger project. One difference is that I have imports to the larger and also own package. One module that seems to crash things are PyYAML (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml') but it seems that I have other problems to with my project structure -

```
my_project
- src
-- my_package
```

So - How do you do runnable apps for MacOS? Any suggestion on books, sites, youtube to study from? Any problems with PyYAML?

More info.
I switched back from my earlier update from bash -

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`
```

I also made a smaller testproject with only one import (PyYAML) and suddenly I could create a project with pip3 install -r requirements.txt and after that I could run the project outside PyCharm with python3 main.py. Could it be the zsh / bash update (I quite dont understand what it is) that mess everything up with no 
modules and pyinstaller?

Comment: check this: https://superuser.com/questions/1164706/how-do-i-make-a-python-file-executable-on-macos-sierra

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment into pycharm?

Comment: Yes - I am using a virtual environment in PyCharm